# Using an executable as library in dune

Tags: ocaml, dune

I'm building a project using dune and I'm facing the following situation. Essentially, my project depends on another project, not developed by me, from which I want to use some parts of the source code.

Here is more or less my project tree

```
my_project/
|---dune-project
|---src/
   |---dune
   |---extrenal-project/
      |---dune-project
      |---dune
      |---src/
         |---dune
   |---src-file.ml
```

The problem is that `external-project` has a `dune` file that builds it as an `executable`, instead of a `library`. Therefore, I cannot include it as a library in my `dune` file. Ideally, I don't want to modify the `dune` file inside of `external-project`.

I've tried a series of combinations. Here is the current status of my `dune` file:

```
(dirs external-project)

(executable
 (name myexec)
 (libraries containers)
 (modules Myexec)
 (promote (until-clean) (into ".."))
)

(env (dev (flags (:standard -warn-error -A))))
```

Which allows me to compile `external-project` correctly, but then does not allow me to reference any of its files. I also tried `(dirs external-project external-project/src)` but to no success.

So, my question is: is there a way for me to reference `external-project` as a library, even though it is build as an `executable`?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you tried vendoring it? https://dune.readthedocs.io/en/stable/dune-files.html?highlight=vendor#vendored-dirs-since-1-11

Comment: Yes, but it didn't work. Nor did including subdirectories with unqualified mode.

Comment: Could you symlink the source file(s) from the external project into their own directory where you could add your own dune file? Or do they change regularly?